# Mongoose don't save if object is null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How **not to insert empty object** i.e `{ }` in Mongoose schema.

Let suppose Mongoose collection is as follows

```
let testCollection = mongoose.Schema({
  someData:{
    type: []
  }
```

Insert in Mongoose collection is as follows

```
let emptyObj = { }

new testCollection({
 someData: emptyObj
}).save()
```

If this code executes, mongoose collection will be like this

```
 db.somecollection.find().pretty()

    {
     "someData" : [
       { }
      ]
    }
```

How to **insert object** in this array **only if the object is not empty**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are no other fields, this can be done with a ternary:

```
const isEmpty = !obj || Object.keys(obj).length;

new testCollection(isEmpty ? { someData: emptyObj } : {}).save()
```

Otherwise this can be done with object spread and short-circuit evaluation in order to avoid repetitions and additional temporary variables:

```
new testCollection({
  someField: 'value',
  ...(isEmpty || { someData: emptyObj })
}).save()
```